# What's the equivalent to django-flatpages in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

How can I build a minimal CMS like Django does with django-flatpages?

I'd prefer a built-in solution to a plugin. I heard of controller caching, does anyone know of another solution?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
script/generate scaffold FlatPage url:string title:string content:text
```

That will create you the model, database migration, unit test stub, view, view helper, controller and route. Enter your database details in `config/database.yml`, run `rake:db:migrate`, point your browser to http://localhost:3000 and off you go!